# jOOQ codegen for enum in another schema

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a setup in Postgres that looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE my_enum AS ENUM ( 'left', 'right');
CREATE TABLE my_table ( direction my_enum not null );

CREATE SCHEMA reporting;
CREATE VIEW reporting.my_table AS SELECT * FROM public.my_table;
```

I have jOOQ using the `reporting` schema. (I'd prefer not to change this.)

I expect the `direction` column in the generated code to have a generated Java enum as its type, but it has type `java.lang.Object`.  Presumably this is because jOOQ cannot see the Postgres enum's definition, since it's outside the `reporting` schema.

I've tried defining the enum in Java code and using jOOQ 3.10's `enumConverter`, but that produces this error during codegen: `org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type USER-DEFINED is not supported in dialect POSTGRES`.

I can work around this using `.cast` and raw SQL, but I was wondering if there's a clean solution I haven't thought of, or if this is a known missing piece in jOOQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should let jOOQ generate the enum for you, from the `public` schema. You can easily exclude all the rest using some regular expressions in your code generator's `<include>` and `<exclude>` tags.

If for some reason this is not a viable approach, do note that the absence of any type information on your column means that you cannot simply use a `Converter`. You would have to implement a data type `Binding`: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/

Comment: This worked, thanks! It had never occurred to me that `inputSchema` was optional.

Comment: @undermountain: Oh, yes indeed, that's a prerequisite :) Could we have improved the manual to make this more clear for you, perhaps?