# How to generate a Java enum from an enum type in PostgreSQL with jOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have the following enum definition:

```sql
create type task_status as enum ('ok', 'fail')
```

A table:

```sql
create table if not exists task
(
    id      uuid default gen_random_uuid() not null primary key,
    status  task_status,
    ...
);
```

And the following codegen config:

```xml
<generator>
    <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>

    <generate>
        <fluentSetters>true</fluentSetters>
        <daos>true</daos>
        <springAnnotations>true</springAnnotations>
        <springDao>true</springDao>
    </generate>

    <database>
        <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
        <includes>task</includes>
        <includeTables>true</includeTables>
        <includeSystemTables>false</includeSystemTables>
        <includeInvisibleColumns>false</includeInvisibleColumns>
        <includeEmbeddables>true</includeEmbeddables>
        <includeRoutines>false</includeRoutines>
        <forcedTypes>
            <forcedType>
                <name>INSTANT</name>
                <includeTypes>timestamptz</includeTypes>
            </forcedType>
        </forcedTypes>
    </database>

    <target>
        ...
    </target>
</generator>
```

When I run codegen, I get:

```java
public class Task implements Serializable {
    
    private Object status;
    ...
}
```

While I found no direct answer on whether jOOQ can indeed generate a Java enum type from this column type, it *sounds* like [it just works for others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795587/jooq-codegen-for-enum-in-another-schema). I am aware that I can implement custom generators or use an enum converter, but I want to know if Java enums can be generated out-of-the-box and I'm just doing it wrong. I'm on jOOQ 3.17.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the enum type in your code generation configuration:

```xml
<includes>task</includes>
```

Do this, instead:

```xml
<includes>task|task_status</includes>
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea the types are included like tables  Thank you!

Comment: Every object type is matched by these regular expressions, [see here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-includes-excludes/). There's a pending feature request to add per-object-type-includes: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5263

Comment: @kaqqao: I do realise that it would be possible to hint this to the user, especially because you didn't *explicitly* exclude the `task_status` object. We could add some `INFO` log and possibly Javadoc to code generation output, as this is usually a mistake by the user when configuring the code generator: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15720

Comment: That would indeed be lovely. Thanks for considering this, much appreciated :)